# From MMDD to day of the year in R

Tags: r, date

I have this .txt file:
http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=0fdswDxF

First column (Date) shows date in month/day
So 0601 is the 1st of June

When I load this into R and I show the data, it removes the first 0 in the data.
So when loaded it looks like:

```
601
602
```

etc
For 1st of June, 2nd of June

For the months 10,11,12, it remains unchanged.

How do I change it back to `0601` etc.?

What I am trying to do is to change these days into the day of the year, for instance,
1st of January (0101) would be 1, and 31st of December would be 365.

There is no leap year to be considered.

I have the code to change this, if my data was shown as 0601 etc, but not as 601 etc.

```
copperNew$Date = as.numeric(as.POSIXct(strptime(paste0("2013",copperNew$Date), format="%Y%m%d")) - 
                              as.POSIXct("2012-12-31"), units = "days")
```

Where Date of course is from the file linked above.

Please ask if you do not consider the description to be good enough.

Comment: What do you mean by number of the year? do you mean 1st of February being day 32, 1st of March being day 60 in non leap years and so forth?

Comment: Yes 1st of february is day 32 :) You are correct

Comment: When reading the file, specify the column class as character, e.g., use the `colClasses` argument of `read.table`.

Comment: Thank you this worked to read the data as 0601 etc again.
But when I do this, how do I then get the dates out as day of the year instead of mmdd?
Because the code written above does not work anymore when it is changed to characters :)

Comment: @user2359612, welcome to SO.  If your question has been answered, please do not forget to mark it as "accepted" by hitting the green check mark next to the answer

Answer (score 4):

```
d<-as.Date("0201", format = "%m%d")
strftime(d, format="%j")
#[1] "032"
```

First you parse your string and obtain Date object which represents your date (notice that it will add current year, so if you want to count days for some specific year add it to your string: `as.Date("1988-0201", format = "%Y-%m%d")`).

Function `strftime` will convert your Date to POSIXlt object and return day of year. If you want the result to be a numeric value, you can do it like this: `as.numeric(strftime(d, format = "%j"))`(Thanks Gavin Simpson)

Comment: +1 You may want to note that `as.numeric(strftime(d, format = "%j"))` will get the DoY as a numeric value.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `colClasses` in the `read.table` function, then convert to `POSIXlt` and extract the year date.  You are over complicating the process.

```
copperNew <- read.table("http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=0fdswDxF", header=TRUE,
colClasses=c("character", "integer", rep("numeric", 3)))

tmp <- as.POSIXlt( copperNew$Date, format='%m%d' )
copperNew$Yday <- tmp$yday
```

The `as.POSIXct` function is able to parse a string without a year (assumes the current year) and computes the day of the year for you.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich, yes, the current year being a leap year needs to be taken into account (unless the user wants to adjust for the leap year if this year is a leap year, then it does the right thing).  There are ways to adjust the above, one of which is the `paste0` with a non-leapyear to the beginning of the string (making sure that there are no extra characters and the date is not a factor), etc.

Comment: @GregSnow: yep, which is why I chose 2011 in my answer to their previous question.

Answer (score 3):

Convert it to `POSIXlt` using a year that is not a leap-year, then access the `yday` element and add 1 (because `yday` is 0 on January 1st).

```
strptime(paste0("2011","0201"),"%Y%m%d")$yday+1
# [1] 32
```

From start-to-finish:

```
x <- read.table("http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=0fdswDxF",
  colClasses=c("character",rep("numeric",5)), header=TRUE)
x$Date <- strptime(paste0("2011",x$Date),"%Y%m%d")$yday+1
```

Comment: Thank you

But I am in need to change a complete dataset and not just get the information for 1 day.

My dataset is this
http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=0fdswDxF

And I need to change the data for the column "Date"

Comment: @user2359612: you simply replace `"0201"` with your vector of dates.  You did not provide a reproducible example, so I cannot be more specific.  The text version of your data set does not tell me what type of R object it is stored in.

Comment: The first works fine fore me. The second makes no sense. How do you expect to convert the string `"Date"` into a date? And I said you needed to replace `"0201"` with your vector of dates; why did you remove the year? You're starting to make me feel sorry for trying to help...

Answer (score 0):

In which language?

If it's something like C#, Java or Javascript, I'd follow these steps:

1-) parse a pair of integers from that column;
2-) create a datetime variable whose day and month are taken from the integers from step one. Set the year to some fixed value, or to the current year.
3-) create another datetime variable, whose date is the 1st of February of the same year as the one in step 2.

The number of the day is the difference in days between the datetime variables, + 1 day.

Comment: The language is R, my problem is I do not have a clue of what syntax to use to do anything of the above

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me:

```
copperNew <- read.table("http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=0fdswDxF", 
                         header=TRUE, sep=" ", colClasses=c("character", 
                                                            "integer", 
                                                            rep("numeric", 3)))

copperNew$diff = difftime(as.POSIXct(strptime(paste0("2013",dat$Date), 
                                     format="%Y%m%d", tz="GMT")),  
                          as.POSIXct("2012-12-31", tz="GMT"), units="days")
```

I had to specify the timezone (`tz` argument in as.POSIXct), otherwise I got two different timezones for the vectors I am subtracting and therefore non-integer days.